# Problem with adding css class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript function wchich I am using is selecting more than one link. It is doing that because I used Regular expression with '^' symbol. I have done it this way because my links looks like that:

```
http://localhost/MainApp/User/UserEdit.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1
```

and value of location.pathname is `/MainApp/User/UserEdit.aspx`
And so I thought that I will check only begining of link and it will work well.

So my Javascript function looks like that:

```
function markActiveLink() {
    var path = location.pathname;
    var links = null;
    if (path) {
        links = $("a[href^='" + path + "']");
    } else {
        links = $("a[href='/']");
    }
    links.parents("li").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
}
```

This function is working quite well and adding css class "current" to `<li>` elements and it's parent `<li>` element.

**Problem:** I have also links that differ only by the ending. And this function trims endings. Those links looks like that:

```
http://localhost//MainApp/User/Order.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=NMO
```

and `http://localhost//MainApp/User/Order.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO`

So they differ only by the ending -> MNO and MO. And when I am selecting one of this links my function is adding css class to them both.

I have tried using `document.location.href` instead of `document.pathname` like that:

```
      function markActiveLink() {
var path = document.location.href;        
            var links = null;
            if (path) {
                links = $("a[href='" + path  + "']");
            } else {
                links = $("a[href='/']");
            }
            links.parents("li").each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
            });
        }
```

But then none of links were selected.

Code of some of menu links look like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserDetails.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&from=user">        
        <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("CurrentUser.Text")%></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserDetails.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&from=user">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("CurrentUser.Text")%>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=NMO">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("NMOrders.Text")%>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=MO">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("MOrders.Text")%>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserPage.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>">
                <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("UserPage.Text")%>
            </a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    [...]
</ul>
```

Menu structure looks like that:

```
<ul>
    <li><a></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a></a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    ...
    </li>
    <li><a></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a></a></li>
        <ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

And on page those links source code looks like that:

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=NMO">
                    User Orders NMO
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO">
                    User Orders MO
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/User/UserPage.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1">
                    User Page
                </a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try function like that:

```
function markActiveLink() {
    var path = location.href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
    var links = null;
    if (path) {
        links = $("a[href='" + path + "']");
    } else {
        links = $("a[href='/']");            
    }
    links.parents("li").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
    });          

}
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: It works great! I used 'var path = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;' but idea is similar.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
 function markActiveLink() {
        $("ul.menu").find("ul").removeClass("current");
        var loc = document.location.href;        
        var $link = null;

        var path = loc.split("?")[1];

        if (path) {
            $link = $('ul.menu li a[href$="' + path  + '"]');
        } else {
            $link = $("ul.menu li a[href$='/']");
        }
        $link.addClass("current");
        $link.parent().addClass("current");
    }
```

and change ur html for ur menu to:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=NMO">
            <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("NMOrders.Text")%>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserOrder.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>&type=MO">
            <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("MOrders.Text")%>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("VirtualDirectory").ToString()%>User/UserPage.aspx?id=<%=pe.UserId%>">
            <%=Me.GetLocalResourceObject("UserPage.Text")%>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I have written code here wrong - I already tried with var path = document.location.href; and then none of links are selected. I am using function: document.write(document.location.href) to check values and it matches my links.

Comment: well i guess the code you have up there is a bit confusing in that case, but so what you are trying to do is be able to select the links different depending on whether they are MNO or MO right??

in this case, just use the "ends with" regex for selectors i.e. a[href$="NMO"] or a[href$="MO"]

Comment: Yes. I have a menu with links. And some of those links differ only by ending. And I want to have selected only one item from menu. I want to select link on menu to current page, so that user would know where he is.

Comment: ok so I'm not sure why you using an each function? ideally you will be selecting only one <li><a href></a></li> element correct?

so would this work? :

$('li a[href="' + document.location.href + '"]').addClass("current");

Comment: I am not good at Javascript and i am not sure why I am using an each function either. And yes I want to select only one <li> element, oh and also it's parent <li> to mark all path.

Comment: try the edited above code in my answer.  I'm assuming you are calling this function in your document.ready correct?

Comment: I am calling this function like that: <script type="text/javascript">
    function markActiveLink() {
        var path = document.location.href;
        var $link = null;
        if (path) {
            $link = $('a[href="' + path + '"]');
        } else {
            $link = $("a[href='/']");
        }
        $link.addClass("current");
        $link.parent().addClass("current");
    }

    markActiveLink(); 
</script>

Comment: try this...

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){markActiveLink();}); function markActiveLink() { var path = document.location.href; var $link = null; if (path) { $link = $('a[href="' + path + '"]'); } else { $link = $("a[href='/']"); } $link.addClass("current"); $link.parent().addClass("current"); } </script>

Comment: if this doesn't work please post the HTML markup for your menu code

Comment: I have tried your code - and still none of links were selected. I have added part of menu source code and how it looks like on page to the question.

Comment: It is half working now: When I select <a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=NMO">User Orders NMO</a> it is working fine. When I select: <a href="/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO">User Orders MO</a> only parent <li> is selected and GrandParent <li> is not selected. But the stranges is when I select <a href="/App/User/UserPage.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1">User Page</a> then more than a half of links in menu (on both levels) are selected.

Comment: I think that I know what was wrong with my first solution to use location.href. location.href have domain name in it (http://localhost) and links doesn't. So it won't match.

Comment: i'm confused what you mean about grandfather li. all I see is one li level

Comment: and yes i realized that problem, my solution should still work

Comment: ohh. also you have to remove the current class

Comment: I have added more code so that it is easier to understand structure of this menu.

Comment: I check your code and still it select half of my menu at one time.

Answer (score 0):

a[href^='" + path + "'] will return all the nodes that start with the value of path, as documented here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

maybe using a[href$='" + path + "'] is what you are looking for since it looks for all nodes having href ending with path.

or just a[href='" + path + "'] should return only one node.

Comment: I have already tried thinks like that. When I used a[href^='" + path + "'] it was selecting more than one menu item. And when I was using a[href='" + path + "'] it was not selecting complicated links.